# What is the best way to handle connection in ef core 2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

Sorry if this is answered earlier, I would like to know what is the best way to handle connection in MVC 6 with EF Core 2.0. Should i use singleton instance (Servics.AddSingleton ) of DBContext or any better way to handle it. If there are multiple instances of DBContext, i will endup having my entities into disconnected state. How to handle that situation then ?

Comment: Never, ever, ever use a singleton context! It's not thread safe and concurrency will make it explode.

Comment: Your title and content don't match.  There is a huge difference between connection and context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's a bit of a pet-peeve, but there is no such thing as MVC 6. There's ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core, where MVC is the older framework running on full .NET and Core is the newer framework that runs on .NET Core.

As @DavidG points out, you should *never* have a context in singleton-scope. Your context should always be in request-scope or what ASP.NET Core's DI container simply calls "Scoped". This will ensure that there's only one instance of your context per request, which is exactly what you want. The fact that other requests will have their own instance should not be an issue unless you're doing nasty non-thread-safe things that cross request-boundaries (which you should not do).

Finally, having detached entities isn't a problem in itself. You simply attach them when you need to do something atomic with them.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. Now that makes me think, what if there are way too many parallel requests, let's say 50,000 requests ? Do you think in this case using entity framewrok is not a good choice or do we need to setup connection pooling somehow ?

Comment: Well, there's an argument to be made that EF is slow, in general, though EF Core has improved a lot on that front. Of course, there's an argument to be made that ORMs in general are slow. If you have a website fielding 50,000 simultaneous requests, all hitting a database, then you probably want to use something like Dapper or just straight ADO.NET. Of course, if your site is fielding that many requests, there's a great many various things you will need to optimize for scale, probably the least of which being your DB access method.